# Show that $\int_{S^{n-1}_+}\frac{1}{\left \langle y,a \right \rangle^n}dS(y)=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\frac{1}{a_1\dots a_n}$

Tags: integration, vector-analysis, surface-integrals

> Let $\mathbb{R}^n_{+}$ be the set of points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with all coordinates positive.
>   Let $S^{n-1}_{+}=S^{n-1}\cap \mathbb{R}^n_{+}$. Let $a=(a_1, \dots ,a_n)\in \mathbb{R}^n_{+}$. Show that:
>   $$\int_{S^{n-1}_+}\frac{1}{\left \langle y,a \right \rangle^n}dS(y)=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\frac{1}{a_1\dots a_n}$$
>   **Hint:** Compute the integral $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n_+}e^{-\left \langle x,a \right \rangle}dx_1\dots dx_n$$ in two different ways.

I've tried to use the hint. The easy way to compute the integral is by Fubini:
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n_+}e^{-\left \langle x,a \right \rangle}dx_1\dots dx_n=
\left ( \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-a_1x_1}dx_1 \right )\dots \left ( \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-a_nx_n}dx_n \right )=\frac{1}{a_1}\dots\frac{1}{a_n}$$
This is a question under the title of "co-area fomula" so the second way should be using the formula to switch to integration on the positive side of all spheres centered at the origin.
But that gives:
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n_+}e^{-\left \langle x,a \right \rangle}dx_1\dots dx_n=
\int_0^{\infty}\left ( \int_{\rho S_{+}^{n-1}}e^{-\left \langle x,a \right \rangle}dS(x)\right ) d\rho$$
And I can't see how on earth can such an expression lead to the desired equality.

No one I know has managed to solve this. I'd very appriciate your help.
Good solutions that do not use the hint will also be welcomed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $I$ denote your last integral and notice that, under the scaling $x \mapsto \rho x$, it can be written as

$$ I
= \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{S_+^{n-1}} e^{-\rho \langle x, a\rangle} \rho^{n-1} 
 \,dS(x) d\rho
= \int_{S_+^{n-1}} \left( \int_{0}^{\infty}  \rho^{n-1} e^{-\langle x, a\rangle \rho} \, d\rho \right) \, dS(x) $$

because now two integral is *decoupled*.<sup>[1]</sup>  Now the inner integral is just the Laplace transform of the function $\rho \mapsto \rho^{n-1}$ evaluated at $\langle x, a\rangle$,<sup>[2]</sup> hence yielding

$$ I = \int_{S_+^{n-1}} \frac{(n-1)!}{\langle x, a\rangle^n} \, dS(x) $$

as desired.

---

**Footnotes.**

1. The change of order of integration is justified because the integrand is non-negative. This follows from [*Tonelli's theorem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli.27s_theorem_for_non-negative_functions), which tells that if the integrand is non-negative then you can interchange the order of two integrals unconditionally.
2. If you are not familiar to this integral, just consider the sequence

   $$ I_n = \int_{0}^{\infty} x^n e^{-sx} \, dx $$

   for a fixed $s > 0$ and use integration by parts to show that the following recursive formula is satisfied:

   $$ I_0 = \frac{1}{s}, \qquad I_{n} = \frac{n}{s} I_{n-1} \quad \forall n \geq 1. $$

   Therefore $I_n = \frac{n!}{s^{n+1}}$ and our case corresponds to $I_{n-1}$ with $s = \langle x, a\rangle$.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I don't know about the Laplace transform so I can't tell where the last expression comes from. If it's possible to explain without Laplace transform I'd happy to hear. Yet, I'm interested to ask how is the change of order of integrals in the first row can be justified.

Comment: Good work, you beat me to it! (+1)

Comment: Great solution! Thank you for your help. BTW, I'm actually familiar with the gamma function, but only now I see that it is relevant here...